# StackExchange RedisTimeoutException

Tags: session, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have recently shifted my project to Redis session. Redis session works perfectly from login till it reach the dashboard. During this time read and write of session are working perfectly. But when I proceed to any inner pages I am getting timeout error as below.

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout performing HGETALL
>   {Key}, inst: 1, queue: 17, qu: 0, qs: 17, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0

Currently my configuration is as below.

```
ConfigurationOptions.Parse("server,connectTimeout=15000,KeepAlive = 30,syncTimeout=15000")
```

Please suggest what to be done to resolve this timeout error ?

Comment: how do you open session / close session ? Is it http server or app ? how do you check your session activity ? explain more of your pbm please

Comment: Actually I am new to Rediss session. I have written the following code in Global.asax to initialize the rediss session also made changes for same in webconfig.



Global_asax.redisConfigOpts = ConfigurationOptions.Parse("{server_ip}")

        RedisConnectionConfig.GetSERedisServerConfig = Function(context As HttpContextBase)
                                                           Return New KeyValuePair(Of String, ConfigurationOptions)("DefaultConnection", Global_asax.redisConfigOpts)
                                                       End Function

Answer (score 1):

I see that the timeout error you are getting is on an HGETALL operation. HGETALL is an O(N) operation where N is the size of the Hash. Could you be trying to fetch too large of a Hash that is timing out?

Also, your error messages don't contain the threadpool or CPU info, which means that you are probably using a very old nuget package version of the StackExchange.Redis client. Upgrading your client to the latest version should help you to get this extra (CPU and threadpool) information in your error messages.